# Extract info from the large file, use newline character in awk regex

Tags: c++, regex, shell, awk

I need to extract some information from the very large file.
I want to extract specific lines using regular expressions.
What is the fastest way to do this?
I'm coding in c++ on linux.

I want to use `grep`, but seems my regex is not working as expected.
For example `\s`, `\w` are not working properly.
In `man grep` is written that `\w`and `[:alnum:]` are synonyms, so, `\w` should work properly but it shouldn't.

I need to use newline characters in my regex, so, I'couldn't use `grep`, therefore, I decided to use `awk`.
How should I use `newline` character in `awk` regex?
Let's consider we have a file (test.txt) with the content below:

> HELLO worl_d5 ;
>  some statement
>  HELLO world1 ;
>  some
>   statement
>  hi
>  hi
>  some statement
>  ...

And I want to get only these lines:

> HELLO worl_d5 ;
>  some statement
>  HELLO world1 ;
>  some
>   statement

I.e., I want to find lines that start with `HELLO` word followed by the space character(s), then some alphanumeric( or containing `/`) word followed by the space character(s) and then, a single `;`. But I want to get this kind of lines when they are followed by the `some statement` line only.

I wrote:

```
awk '/HELLO[[:space:]]([[:alnum:]]|\/)+[[:space:]];\n[[:space:]]*some[[:space:]] statement [[:space:]];/ { print }' test.txt
```

But I couldn't get needed results.

Or just provide an example where `newline` is used in regex.

Comment: The fastest way to get a useful answer to your question is to be a lot more specific.  And include some code showing what you're thinking so far.

Comment: You may want to start with why you think grep is failing and what your data looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I was using `[:space:]` instead of `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: `\s` and `\w` are not portable, use `[[:space:]]` and `[[:alnum:]_]` (or similar) POSIX character classes instead.

Comment: @EdMorton, could you please help me? What is the `newline` character in `awk` regex, or what option should I use?

Comment: Newline is `\n`. Without you posting some sample input and expected output and clarifying your requirements we can't help you any further.

Comment: You said you want to get some specific lines but you didn't tell us WHY. Describe what is it about those lines that we could program some tool to identify them separately from the other lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `pcregrep` and `newline` just worked fine!

```
pcregrep -M '(HELLO[[:space:]]([[:alnum:]]|\/|_)+[[:space:]];)[\r\n]([[:space:]]*some[[:space:]]statement[[:space:]];)' test.txt
```